# can't add all data to db c# in vs 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server

this my project i can't add all data  but table "Re" have data when i input data please help me.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\Project\c#\DB\db2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("connected");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("disconnect");
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String date = dateTimePicker1.Text;
        String re_date = dateTimePicker2.Text;
        String re_p = null;
        String pay = null;
        //recieve
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            re_p = "this place";
        }
        else{
            if (radioButton2.Checked)
                re_p = "Fax";
            else
                re_p = "post";
        }
        //Payment
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            pay = "money";
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
                pay = "receipt";
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
                pay = "transfer";
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
                pay = "unpaid";

            //command insert
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Profile values('" + ID.Text.Trim() + "','" + date + "','" + name.Text.Trim() + "','" + adr.Text.Trim() + "','" + tel.Text.Trim() + "','" + fax.Text.Trim() + "','" + mail.Text.Trim() + "','" + obj.Text.Trim() + "','" + num.Text.Trim() + "','" + syn.Text.Trim() + "','" + namet.Text.Trim() + "')";

            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Data values('" + ID.Text.Trim() + "','" + mo.Text.Trim() + "','" + pro.Text.Trim() + "','" + fat.Text.Trim() + "','" + fiber.Text.Trim() + "','" + fiberh.Text.Trim() + "','" + ash.Text.Trim() + "','" + asha.Text.Trim() + "','" + cal.Text.Trim() + "','" + phos.Text.Trim() + "','" + ndf.Text.Trim() + "','" + adf.Text.Trim() + "','" + adfa.Text.Trim() + "','" + en.Text.Trim() + "','" + sodium.Text.Trim() + "','" + pow.Text.Trim() + "','" + am.Text.Trim() + "','" + tan.Text.Trim() + "','" + uri.Text.Trim() + "','" + me.Text.Trim() + "')";

            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Re values('" + ID.Text.Trim() + "','" + re_p + "','" + post.Text.Trim() + "','" + re_date + "','" + recieve.Text.Trim() + "','" + sent.Text.Trim() + "','" + pay + "','" + money.Text.Trim() + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("complete");

        }        
    }
```

Comment: please use parameters instead of string concatination for sql. what linenumber breaks? and does it show the messagebox with connected?

Comment: You're setting `cmd.CommandText` three times, overwriting the previous values each time.

Comment: i don't have any error and i can't add data to table "Profile"&"Data"

Comment: How i do? @AndrewArnold

Comment: please use switch and cases for comboBox1.SelectedIndex

Comment: Thank a lot all people

Comment: Oh!  i forgot!!!  i have problem my data is thai language and i see "????" in data is thai language  someone help!!!  Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `cmd.CommandText` every time and hence data is inserted only in `Re` table..

simplest approach can be after every `cmd.CommandText` write `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0: 
        pay = "money"; break;
    case 1:
        pay = "receipt"; break;
    case 2:
        pay = "transfer"; break;
    case 3:
        pay = "unpaid"; break;
}

cmd.CommandText = "insert into Profile values(@id, @d,'" + name.Text.Trim() + "','" + adr.Text.Trim() + "','" + tel.Text.Trim() + "','" + fax.Text.Trim() + "','" + mail.Text.Trim() + "','" + obj.Text.Trim() + "','" + num.Text.Trim() + "','" + syn.Text.Trim() + "','" + namet.Text.Trim() + "')";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", ID.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d", date);
// etc
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Data values('" + ID.Text.Trim() + "','" + mo.Text.Trim() + "','" + pro.Text.Trim() + "','" + fat.Text.Trim() + "','" + fiber.Text.Trim() + "','" + fiberh.Text.Trim() + "','" + ash.Text.Trim() + "','" + asha.Text.Trim() + "','" + cal.Text.Trim() + "','" + phos.Text.Trim() + "','" + ndf.Text.Trim() + "','" + adf.Text.Trim() + "','" + adfa.Text.Trim() + "','" + en.Text.Trim() + "','" + sodium.Text.Trim() + "','" + pow.Text.Trim() + "','" + am.Text.Trim() + "','" + tan.Text.Trim() + "','" + uri.Text.Trim() + "','" + me.Text.Trim() + "')";
// clear cmd.parameters and use parameters for the above statement and all next statements
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Re values('" + ID.Text.Trim() + "','" + re_p + "','" + post.Text.Trim() + "','" + re_date + "','" + recieve.Text.Trim() + "','" + sent.Text.Trim() + "','" + pay + "','" + money.Text.Trim() + "')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("complete");
```